# How can I map @ManyToOne when a column (implicitly) refers part of some other table’s compound PK?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, many-to-one, composite-primary-key

I'm writing entity classes for existing tables and I'm seeing, somewhat weird, tables look like this.

The `parent` table defines some codes with categories.

```
parent
----
category VARCHAR PK
code     VARCHAR PK
```

And the child table has a column has values equals to parent’s code column.
Note that there is no FK for that.

```
child
-----
code     VARCHAR - no FK for parent/category
```

I suspect that the table designer relied on web UI for integrity.

Say.

```
parent table
category code
-------------
'a'      'c'
'b'      'x'
'b'      'y'

child table << this table is supposed to use 'b' category.
code
-------------
'x'             // implicitly refer 'b' - 'x'
'y'             // implicitly refer 'b' - 'y'
```

How can I make it work with `@ManyToOne` with implicit mapping?

```java
@Entity
@IdClass(ParentId.class)
class Parent {

    @Id String category;

    @Id String code;
}
```

```java
@Entity
class Child {

    static final String IMPLICIT_CATEGORY = "b";

    //@Column(name = "code");
    //private String code; // Works, of course.

    @ManyToOne
    private Parent parent; // Can I do this?
}
```

How can I do the `@ManyToOne` in `Some` entity class? Is it even possible?

Comment: Is code 'x' unique within the parent table? If not, looks like the design is more a many to many, where a child can be associated to many parents. If it is unique, then looks like maybe the table designer made a mistake and could have just used code as the unique pk; you can certainly just mark that as your ID within the parent entity - it doesn't have to exactly match the database, it just helps. You could have a composite pk and then child only reference the code, but this isn't allowed in JPA (it breaks caching) but will work with providers - you'll have to look at their docs for support

Comment: @Chris Thanks for the comment. No the `code` column in `parent` table is not unique alone. That's (another) problem, I agree. The table designer's mistake is that he or she decided the `child` table's `code` column MIGHT maps the the `parent` rows whose `category` column is specific. Say, via Web UI, via MyBatis' SQL.

Comment: You will have to map the child.code field with a basic mapping to set your self (if performing modifications), but you can map it as a OneToMany specifying a join column (insertable/updateable=false) from CODE in parent to CODE in child. If you want parent to have a list of children, just do the same thing on the other side, setting a read-only join column marking the child's CODE as a foreign key to parent table's CODE. Hibernate will have ways to get around the JPA validation since full PKs are not being referenced at all - I don't know it well enough to give a full answer.